# Python `pkgutil.get_data` disrupts future imports

Tags: python, package, python-module

Consider the following package structure:

```
.
├── module
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── submodule
│       ├── attribute.py
│       ├── data.txt
│       └── __init__.py
└── test.py
```

and the following piece of code:

```
import pkgutil
data = pkgutil.get_data('module.submodule', 'data.txt')
import module.submodule.attribute
retval = module.submodule.attribute.hello()
```

Running this will raise the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    retval = module.submodule.attribute.hello()
AttributeError: module 'module' has no attribute 'submodule'
```

However, if you run the following:

```
import pkgutil
import module.submodule.attribute
data = pkgutil.get_data('module.submodule', 'data.txt')
retval = module.submodule.attribute.hello()
```

or

```
import pkgutil
import module.submodule.attribute
retval = module.submodule.attribute.hello()
```

it works fine.

Why does running `pkgutil.get_data` disrupt the future import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this was a great question and a great opportunity to learn something new about python's import system. So let's dig in!

If we look at [the implementation of `pkgutil.get_data`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/pkgutil.py#L597-L637) we see something like this:

```py
def get_data(package, resource):
    spec = importlib.util.find_spec(package)
    if spec is None:
        return None
    loader = spec.loader
    if loader is None or not hasattr(loader, 'get_data'):
        return None
    # XXX needs test
    mod = (sys.modules.get(package) or
           importlib._bootstrap._load(spec))
    if mod is None or not hasattr(mod, '__file__'):
        return None

    # Modify the resource name to be compatible with the loader.get_data
    # signature - an os.path format "filename" starting with the dirname of
    # the package's __file__
    parts = resource.split('/')
    parts.insert(0, os.path.dirname(mod.__file__))
    resource_name = os.path.join(*parts)
    return loader.get_data(resource_name)
```

And the answer to your question is in this part of the code:

```py
    mod = (sys.modules.get(package) or
           importlib._bootstrap._load(spec))
```

It looks at the already loaded packages and if the package we're looking for (`module.submodule` in this example) exists it uses it and if not, then tries to load the package using `importlib._bootstrap._load`.

So let's look at the [implementation of `importlib._bootstrap._load`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py#L692-L702) to see what's going on.

```py
def _load(spec):
    """Return a new module object, loaded by the spec's loader.
    The module is not added to its parent.
    If a module is already in sys.modules, that existing module gets
    clobbered.
    """
    with _ModuleLockManager(spec.name):
        return _load_unlocked(spec)
```

Well, There's right there! The doc says "The module is not added to its parent."

It means the `submodule` module is loaded but it's not added to the `module` module. So when we try to access the `submodule` via `module` there's no connection, hence the `AtrributeError`.

It makes sense for the `get_data` method to use this function as it just wants some other file in the package and there is no need to import the whole package and add it to its parent and its parents' parent and so on.

to see it yourself I suggest using a debugger and setting some breakpoints. Then you can see what happens step by step along the way.

Comment: Yep, I actually went and did some tracking myself (but forgot to update this question).  I get that loading just the file should not also load `module` but the problem is, even after importing via `import module.submodule.attribute` (which should definitely load module) it still fails.  I think this is because `get_data` caches `module` in a strange way that is not later updated with a regular import.  This seems like unintended behavior.

Comment: Oh, yeah! sure. the caching part you mentioned happens in the `sys.modules`. When you try to `import` the module. it first looks it up in the `sys.modules` dictionary and since it has been loaded before by `get_data`, it doesn't try to load it again and just uses the already loaded module which not loaded correctly(!) since it hasn't been added to its parent.

Comment: Right, so I wonder if the behavior of `get_data` should be changed to properly import the module.  Hopefully someone responds to my issue here https://bugs.python.org/msg375149 :) Thanks for your input

Comment: Actually, I don't think the behavior should change. It's important to first import everything you want then doing the other stuff. However, there could be some ways to prevent this from happening but I don't think it's necessary.